# Returning Tkinter Treeview iid

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I have a treeview and have inserted some data into it as shown below.

```
self.tree.insert('', 'end', iid="test1", text="test a", values=("data1", "data2"))
```

This adds an entry to the end of the treeview with text "test a" and column values of "data1" and "data2".

The iid has been set to "test1".

I would like to return the value of iid of an item in the treeview so that I can use it for some other function (I will be storing a file path in this iid)

I tried using treeview.item() and this returned the following dictionary without the iid:

```
{'version': 'data1', 'author': 'data2'}
```

(where version and author are the column headings)

So my question: is there a simple way to return the iid of a given row/entry to the treeview?

Comment: Item selected > Press a run button > the iid is used (it is a file path) to start some subprocess.

Comment: use `tree.identify(event.x, event.y)`

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ It looks like I may have something working along the same lines as that. Thanks. Do you know what `iid` stands for?

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. If you'd like to submit your comments as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get  the `iid` you can use the [`identify()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html) function:

```
tree.identify(event.x, event.y) # item at row "x" and column "y"
```

The  `iid`  argument stands for *item identifier* which is unique for each item, and you can give it the value you want.

Comment: this is exactly the same question but an error is produced, any idea why? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43673883/python-who-can-tell-me-why-this-wont-work-example-provided?

Comment: I may answer you by  the end of the day, I am busy right now @new_to_coding

Comment: thank you for your response but don't worry about it, someone has responded with a working solution, which you may want to check out anyway, take care

Answer (score 3):

Learning Python, found no answer to this question here that I liked, so I finally figured out what I wanted and thought I would post what I found. iid = tree.focus() returns the information requested.

in my treeview i added this code:

```
for item in tree.selection():
    item_child = tree.get_children(item)
    item = tree.item(item)
    iid = tree.focus()
    print ("iid = ", iid, "Item = ", item, "Child iid's =", item_child)
```

this is my result from the code:

`{'text': 'TRAINS', 'image': '', 'values': '', 'open': 0, 'tags': ['m']}
iid =  1 Item =  {'text': 'TRAINS', 'image': '', 'values': '', 'open': 0, 'tags': ['m']} Child iid's = ('8', '9', '10')`

Notice at the beginning of line two of the result the iid is listed as "1" which is the correct iid for the item. All treeview items I select returned the correct iid.

Hope this helps the next person a little.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is `iid=tree.focus()`