# Tkinter treeview get iid python

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I tried to get the iid of a specific item from a treeview from Tkinter.

For example if I create :

```
tree.insert("", "end", iid=str(1), text="a", values="a")           
tree.insert("", "end", iid=str(2), text="b", values="b")
tree.insert("", "end", iid=str(3), text="c", values="c")
```

So, this is what I can get from a function with the event :

`item = tree.identify('item', event.x, event.y)`
Which return something like : 'I00B'

But how can I get the iid from the item selected ? So for example 1, 2 or 3.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning Tkinter Treeview iid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043996/returning-tkinter-treeview-iid)

Comment: Why are the two tree variables not the same: `tree` and `treeSequences`?

Comment: @acw1668 I correct it sorry.

Comment: @qWx when I write just tree.identify(event.x, event.y), I get the following error : No value for argument 'y' in method callpylint(no-value-for-parameter)

Comment: Try `tree.focus()`.

Comment: tree.focus() returns the same 'I00B'

Comment: It returns 1, 2 or 3 when `tree.focus()` is used using your posted code.

Comment: Yes, when I run the few lignes above it works, but with my code which is more complex it doesn't work.

Comment: Then you need to provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).